# R printing a string and then a list

Tags: r, string

```
mylist <- c(0,1,4)
```

Desired output:

```
A list: 0 1 4
```

What I've tried includes:

```
print(c('A list:', mylist))

print(paste('A list:', mylist))

print(paste('A list:', paste(mylist)))
```

None of these do what I want.

Comment: Maybe `message('A list: ',paste0(mylist,collapse = ','))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cat` instead.

```
cat("A list:", mylist)
# A list: 0 1 4
```